# To place menu component inside the column of the table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `table` component, In the `table component` i want to place `menu`button in last row like this:
[image]

Actually i have added the `menu` button inside 3rd column and gave `float:right;`, but i want to add this button inside the `table` by creating another column.How  to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the button inside table.

On your component declare a new display column named something like `actions` :

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [ your_rest_declarations...,'actions'];
```

Then add this to your view:

```
    <!-- Actions -->
   <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <button mat-icon-button >
          <mat-icon aria-label="actions">more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Result:

[image]